# My code is malfunctioning, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

I've recently been trying to make a dark/light mode feature and I'm really confused as to what went wrong.

I made three functions: toggleTheme(), which checks if dark mode is on, and if it is, it runs lightTheme(). Otherwise, it runs darkTheme(). I know that toggleTheme is working, so it must be the light and darkTheme functions that don't work as intended. Here's my code:

```js
var vuey = new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
    darkModeStatus: "Off"
  }
});

var themeColors = {
  lightModeBg: "#ddd",
  darkModeBg: "#303030"
}

function toggleTheme() {
  if (vuey.darkModeStatus == "On") {
    lightTheme();
  } else {
    darkTheme();
  }
}

function lightTheme() {
  $("h1"), $("h2"), $("h3"), $("h4"), $("h5").css("color", "black");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = themeColors.lightModeBg;
  vuey.darkModeStatus = "Off";
}

function darkTheme() {
  $("h1"), $("h2"), $("h3"), $("h4"), $("h5").css("color", "white");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = themeColors.lightModeBg;
  vuey.darkModeStatus = "On";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="A clock website I'm making to improve my web development skills" />

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title>Clock</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="settings">
      <h1>ok</h1>
      <button id="themeButton" onclick="toggleTheme()">Dark Mode: {{ darkModeStatus }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Nothing happens whatsoever except vuey.darkModeStatus updating.
How do I fix this?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not how jquery works `$("h1"), $("h2"), $("h3"), $("h4"), $("h5").css("color", "black");` that would only turn the last h5 to black. What you want is this format `$("h4, h5").css("color", "black");`

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: I have also linked to multiple selector jquery doc so you can have a read if you are interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery selector is wrong

`$("h1"), $("h2"), $("h3"), $("h4"), $("h5").css("color", "black");`

That would only turn the last h5 to black.

What you want is this format

`$("h4, h5").css("color", "black");`

For more info, go https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

See your example below, click on full page link if you don't see the toggle button

```js
var vuey = new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
    darkModeStatus: "Off"
  }
});

var themeColors = {
  lightModeBg: "#ddd",
  darkModeBg: "#303030"
}

function toggleTheme() {
  if (vuey.darkModeStatus == "On") {
    lightTheme();
  } else {
    darkTheme();
  }
}

function lightTheme() {
  $("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5").css("color", "black");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = themeColors.lightModeBg;
  vuey.darkModeStatus = "Off";
}

function darkTheme() {
  $("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5").css("color", "white");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = themeColors.lightModeBg;
  vuey.darkModeStatus = "On";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="settings">
    <h1>ok</h1>
    <button id="themeButton" onclick="toggleTheme()">Dark Mode: {{ darkModeStatus }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to have two error
major one your both functions are setting **themeColors.lightModeBg** this needs to be changed and 2nd one your jquery doesn't seems to be right $("h1"), $("h2"), $("h3"), $("h4"), $("h5").css("color", "white") this one so I changed that to $("h1").css("color", "white") in both function below is the code its working now

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="A clock website I'm making to improve my web development skills" />

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <title>Clock</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="settings">
                <h1>ok</h1>
                <button id="themeButton" onclick="toggleTheme()">Dark Mode: {{ darkModeStatus }}</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var vuey = new Vue({
                el: "#main",
                data: {
                    darkModeStatus: "Off"
                }
            });

            var themeColors = {
                lightModeBg: "#ddd",
                darkModeBg: "#303030"
            }

            function toggleTheme() {
                if (vuey.darkModeStatus == "On") {
                    lightTheme();
                } else {
                    darkTheme();
                }
            }

            function lightTheme() {
                $("h1").css("color", "black");
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = themeColors.lightModeBg;
                vuey.darkModeStatus = "Off";
            }

            function darkTheme() {
                $("h1").css("color", "white");
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = themeColors.darkModeBg;
                vuey.darkModeStatus = "On";
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #ddd;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both functions are indicating

```
backgroundColor = themeColors.lightModeBg
```

Just change lightModeBg to darkModeBg